# Is there a way to exactly solve this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-equations

Is there a way to determine $\theta_c$ in the following integral equation:

$$\int_{-\theta_c}^{\theta_c} d\theta \, \exp (a \cos\theta)=1,$$

where $a$ belongs to positive reals?

Comment: Did you already try using a Taylor-Series for the exponential term?

Comment: @Max Taylor-series in small $a$ compared to $2\pi$ (or $\theta_c$)? I want to get a general answer, especially in the large $a$ limit. I tried out some standard techniques like integration by parts etc. and Mathematica as well, to no avail (apart from numerics, since I am interested in the exact answer).

Comment: in first place note that $\int_{-\theta_c}^{\theta_c} \exp (a \cos\theta)d\theta=2\int_{0}^{\theta_c} \exp (a \cos\theta)d\theta $

Comment: There is no exact answer. Go for numerics.

Comment: $\int_{-t}^t\exp(a \cos(\theta))\;d\theta$ can be evaluated in closed form (in terms of Bessel functions) only for certain specific $t$, such as $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a>0$, the integrand has a maximum at $\theta=0$. Writing the series for $\cos$ around zero, we find$^\dagger$

$$ e^a \int_{-\theta_0}^{\theta_0} d\theta \ \exp( -a \theta^2 /2)=e^a \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\theta_0 \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}} \right)=1$$

Rearranging

$$\operatorname{erf}\left(\theta_0 \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}} \right)=e^{-a} \sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi}} $$

Apply inverse $\operatorname{erf}$

$$ \theta_0= \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \operatorname{erf}^{-1} \left(e^{-a} \sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi}}\right) $$

The argument of $\operatorname{erf}^{-1}$ above goes to zero exponentially fast as $a\rightarrow\infty$. The [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions) for $\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(z)$ around $z=0$ is

$$ \operatorname{erf}^{-1}(z)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}z+O(z^2) ,\  z\rightarrow0$$

We are left with

$$ \theta_0 \sim \frac{e^{-a}}{2} \ \ , \ \ a\rightarrow\infty$$

Here is a plot of the original integral: $\int_{-\theta_0}^{\theta_0}d\theta \exp(a \cos\theta)$, numerically evaluated with $\theta_0=e^{-a}/2$. We see that 'large $a$' means modest values of $a>1$.

[image]

$\dagger$ The justification of what we are doing is the same as the justification for [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.